# TCP - Urgent flag, when is it needed?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory

I understand the meaning of this field, and how it is used.

But I can't find an example for when it is needed, I read that it is used in Telnet, why?
When do I need this flag?

Comment: Related post: [Is TCP URG (urgent data) acknowledged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241437/is-tcp-urg-urgent-data-acknowledged/40911903#40911903)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is essentially obsolete.  But Jeremy Stretch has a [good write-up](http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/mar/2/tcp-flags-psh-and-urg/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Because telnet is connecting to a remote computer, we want to be able to have the commands we type executed right after we typed them.
That is why they are flagged with URG flag.

Comment: Nope, it says URG is used when transmitting a break.  That's a special input on a terminal, which is not transmitted as a normal character by telnet (or by the serial lines where it was originally used).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key#Teleprinter

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say telnet is initiated from a client. If the server,for some reason cannot pass requested data to client ( since client is advertising window 0) - the command just hangs.

To avoid this, the server sends a segment with urg flag set along with the urg pointer set too.

The client once reading this will have to accept data from the server.